# How do I find a word repeated twice or thrice using regex backreferencing?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am learning regex and I have tried finding cat that was repeated twice and I found it.

```
import re
f = "cat bat rat cat cat cat"
print(re.findall(r'(cat) \1',f))
```

But when I want to check if the word was repeated twice and use

```
print(re.findall(r'(cat) \2',f))
```

I get an error.

Answer (score 2):

The number after the backslash indicates which capturing group you're referring to, not how many times it should occur. Use `{n}` to repeat the previous selector `n` times.

The proper solution would be: [`r'(cat)(?: \1){2}'`](https://regex101.com/r/yE2uW6/1)

Here I'm creating a non-capturing group (i.e. a group which cannot be referenced) with `(?: ... )` so the space and the back reference are grouped together. This way I get a selector which selects them both and can be repeated with `{n}`.
Depending on your text input, you might want to replace the space with `\s` (i.e. any whitespace) and/or append a `+` to match cases where multiple spaces or tabs are separating the words.

Also it might be useful to use word boundaries `\b` like so:
[`r'\b(cat)(?: \1){2}\b'`](https://regex101.com/r/yE2uW6/3) so you won't match `'bobcat cat cat'` or `'cat cat cats'`

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**: `\b(\w+)\s\1(\s\1)?\b`

**Long Answer**

You need a word which is repeated *twice OR thrice*, thus,

- `\w+` will match all the words
- followed by a space `\s`
- but you want exact word repeated previously, so you wrap the already written `\w` within a `()` to group it - so it becomes `(\w+)\s`
- you now back reference the above and it becomes `(\w+)\s\1`. At this stage you have all words which are repeated twice
- for optionally (`?`) having the same word appear thrice, you say `\s\1?` - which means optionally (represented by a `?`) check for the same word after space, so making it optional, put it in a group again like `(\s\1)?`

  - finally, you want only the full words to match and thus, pre-pend and append with the `\b` i.e. word break to separate them

which becomes `\b(\w+)\s\1(\s\1)?\b`

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?:(cat)\s??\b){3}
```

*In words:*

Look for a word boundary, which is three times followed by:
The character sequence 'cat', which itself is followed by an optional white space (if possible not) and a necessary word boundary.
Capture 'cat' in case of a match.

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/yH7bG9/1)

---

*Python implementation:*

```
import re
f = "cat bat rat cat cat cat hot dog cat cat cat"
re.findall(r'\b(?:(cat)\s??\b){3}', f)
# result: ['cat', 'cat']
```

use re.search when it's just about the question, if the three cats occur and not about how often.